# Camera/Compass/GPS

Tags: android, tree, gps

I was wondering if anyone could explain or clear me out -- I am currently doing some project to identify trees using android. I suppose the main components I must use at this project is GPS, Camera API and Compass (Please let me know if anyone can think anything) -- I am still in a middle of researching about the project and the possible problems that might arise during implement the project for example if there are two trees are in the same line of sight or same line (overlapping), what information is going to be displayed? How I can tell my software that I am actually want to display the front tree not the back of the tree? What sort of information or API will determine this? I mean does the camera or compass or GPS or even the database of the location of tree will determine it?

Can anyone please give me some idea, how I can tackle this kind of problem? Or perhaps if anyone know any tutorials that I can learn etc?

Much appreciated.
theBorneo

Comment: Basically I want to know which direction the user is facing and the user current location is. How can we tell which tree is being display if there are an overlapping trees?

I know that we have to use GPS, compass, camera API even the location of the tree for the database - BUT how can all of these work together so we can get determine and display the tree that we are pointing our phone at?

Any suggestions on this or idea, how I can approach this problems? 
Much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do? There are a host of research laboratories that are trying to get computer vision to work well..

Comment: What I would like to do is; If we are using an android phone, How can determine and identify which such of object e.g. tree that we are pointing to if there are two overlapping tree in the same line of sight? As far as I understood the GPS API only tell you your current location. It did not tell which object you are pointing to. 

And I think the compass but tell us which direction we are pointing and facing too as well as the camera? But How these all work together so that the object we want to display on the android is the one we point to say front tree not the back of it? 

Any ideas?

Comment: My advice is to change your project. This is a very comprehensive field where people spend their lives working on. And now you want to create everything without having any knowledge of it. So either change your project, or simplify it. Computer Vision is very difficult area and you need a lot of time and power to understand it. Only after that you can write software.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - Well I am not trying to do a computer vision on here. The project did not involve computer vision at all. All it said that I need to know whcih direction of the users are facing and pointing their phone at. As I said earlier if there are an overlapping trees then how can the user determine which tree the user want to display? How can we tell if, we can to display the info of the front tree not the back one? I assume we need the compass and range or something like that but I am not 100% sure.

Any ideas would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no existing api that would let you determine this specifically. I can image that you could estimate object identifications based on gps location. If you had waypoints in front, you could use the compass to get a direction and then approximate the gps region in front of you. Then try to see if you know of any prior waypoints that are in that area. Obviously, the one you see in direct line sight is the closest, and this would probably be the heuristic.

The camera will have almost no use in this case other than a view finder. If you are looking to segment images in order to differentiate between different objects, consider this impossible with google api, or any mobile application. This is difficult enough to do for professional researchers who can isolate variables..

The gps approximations are pretty trivial, however I am not confident as to how accurate or often a compass returns direction.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, what do you mean by waypoints here?
I agree with you that as we pointed which direction we want the object is and also with the compass navigation and direction - I got the idea that the closest object would be displayed.

Do I need to learn about camera API in this case? I am not talking about image recognition but I am trying to think maybe there is a way of doing it e.g. augmented reality stuff or similar? 

It seems like what you mention here all I need to learn is the GPS API and compass navigation (in degree 0 degree to 359.99 degree for the direction view)
Idea?

Comment: So i guess for this system to be feasible, you need to record the locations of each of your trees. Then, you can look to see if they are close, later. You'll have to know enough of the camera api to display the live view of the camera. Then, you can simply add a view to display info. It will be pretty difficult to have the view follow the tree with just compass info, so it may be impossible. You'll just display some kind of view ontop of the camera view. You'll need passing familiarity with camera and compass API to implement all of this. The same with gps, unless you are optimizing battery.

Comment: Thanks again for the input, So here are the list:
1. List the location of the tree (using GPS? or grid? or coordinates?)
2. Learn how the camera API works? (Any suggestion for this topic / tutorials?)
So basically when the user point the camera to a particular object / tree and at this moment the camera is active, user click the button info, then the info of the tree will be displayed together with the image of the tree. That is what I want to achieve.
3. Learn about compass API
4. How the map and location interact? 

If I can get these info it seems like the project is feasible. Idea?

Comment: I don't think you'll need to mess with the map api. Just stick with location services. All you need to do is record the lat and long of the trees. Then later, you can just do some simple arithmetic to find the closest tree in the field of vision.
Forgive me if i'm wrong, but it sounds like you've only dabbled with android. The best way to learn things for this project, is to divide the major parts (camera, compass, and gps) into pieces, learning from the android documentation. Once you have those tested well in separate activities, then you can join them into one program.